# Tomcat 7 error about LeaseException querying an EMR cluster

Tags: tomcat, hbase, elastic-map-reduce

I am getting below error while connecting to the EMR cluster using Tomcat server and Hbase as the database.
I have made the changes suggested at http://www.nosql.se/2012/05/hbase-scanner-leaseexception/
and I have also rebooted the clusters suggested as here : http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hbase-user/201209.mbox/%3CCAOcnVr3R-LqtKhFsk8Bhrm-YW2i9O6J6Fhjz2h7q6_sxvwd2yw%40mail.gmail.com%3E

---

HTTP Status 500 - org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.LeaseException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.LeaseException: lease '5811533108977417332' does not exist at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.Leases.removeLease(Leases.java:231) at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.next(HRegionServer.java:2136) at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor19.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.WritableRpcEngine$Server.call(WritableRpcEngine.java:369) at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseServer$Handler.run(HBaseServer.java:1326)

type Exception report

message org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.LeaseException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.LeaseException: lease '5811533108977417332' does not exist at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.Leases.removeLease(Leases.java:231) at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.next(HRegionServer.java:2136) at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor19.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.WritableRpcEngine$Server.call(WritableRpcEngine.java:369) at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseServer$Handler.run(HBaseServer.java:1326)

description The server encountered an internal error (org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.LeaseException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.LeaseException: lease '5811533108977417332' does not exist at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.Leases.removeLease(Leases.java:231) at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.next(HRegionServer.java:2136) at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor19.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.WritableRpcEngine$Server.call(WritableRpcEngine.java:369) at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseServer$Handler.run(HBaseServer.java:1326) ) that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.LeaseException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.LeaseException: lease '5811533108977417332' does not exist
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.Leases.removeLease(Leases.java:231)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.next(HRegionServer.java:2136)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor19.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.WritableRpcEngine$Server.call(WritableRpcEngine.java:369)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseServer$Handler.run(HBaseServer.java:1326)
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AbstractClientScanner$1.hasNext(AbstractClientScanner.java:44)
    Query.doGet(Query.java:64)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
root cause

org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.LeaseException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.LeaseException: lease '5811533108977417332' does not exist
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.Leases.removeLease(Leases.java:231)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.next(HRegionServer.java:2136)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor19.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.WritableRpcEngine$Server.call(WritableRpcEngine.java:369)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseServer$Handler.run(HBaseServer.java:1326)
sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor15.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    org.apache.hadoop.hbase.RemoteExceptionHandler.decodeRemoteException(RemoteExceptionHandler.java:96)
    org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallable.call(ScannerCallable.java:149)
    org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallable.call(ScannerCallable.java:42)
    org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ServerCallable.withRetries(ServerCallable.java:164)
    org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.next(ClientScanner.java:279)
    org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AbstractClientScanner$1.hasNext(AbstractClientScanner.java:41)
    Query.doGet(Query.java:64)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.28 logs.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.28

Comment: Lease Exception in this example is the IP lease used by your server..  What about flushing and re-using your DNS Cache?  If that does not work, there maybe something tromping on you in DNS.  You may have to work with your network folks to be sure there are no conflicts, tombstoned entries, etc.

Comment: Does restarting the cluster should suffice the method what you are suggesting. I tried after restarting the clusters. Throws me the same error. Also I am trying Amazon AWS services to accomplish my task.

Comment: My hbase-site.xml looks like this with other settings in place: <property<name>hbase.regionserver.lease.period</name<value>900000</value> <!-- 9000 000, 15 minutes --></property>
<property><name>hbase.rpc.timeout</name><value>9000000</value> <!-- 15 minutes --></property>
<property><name>hbase.rpc.shortoperation.timeout</name>
<value>9000000</value> <!-- 15 minutes --></property>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try improving the performance by using caching.

```
<property>
<name>hbase.client.scanner.caching</name>
<value>100</value>
</property> 
</configuration>
```

Sometime the regionserver automatically hog down and cause  lease expired